# pgfgantt spans width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, width, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to draw [Gantt chart](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf), where:

[image]

is generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}

    \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}

\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

I would like it span all the width. So I played with `\begin{ganttchart}[x unit=10mm]{1}{12}` and got:

[image]

How to make pgfgantt span all i.e. `\textwidth`?

Using `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to check the position helps, but is there a side effect? Looks like chart moves a bit to the top left.

[image]

Comment: One option is to create a separate file, then include the PDF as graphics with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...pdf}`

Comment: I believe you meant **span** (not *spam*). Please edit your question....

Comment: Also, do you mean `\textwidth` or something else?

Comment: Sure, `\textwidth` would be nice.

Comment: It might be difficult to do it automatically, because you need to reserve some space for the labels and `pgfgantt` does not yet know the size of the labels when the title bar is generated. So it may be easier just to manually play around with the `x unit` value (for each of your charts if you have more than one).

Comment: If you add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to the preamble of your document, you will realize that you are almost there. I would like to argue that a small distance at the right end is better than overshooting.